# File not opening in Office Web Apps even after installing and deploying

Tags: office-web-apps

My Sharepoint site opens file in Native Word client rather then in office Web App on browser.

I have gone through [Configuration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx) and [Deployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx) documents. Still the file Edit opens in Microsoft Word.

How would I be able to find, what is wrong? Is there any tool/command I can see any error?

Let me know if require more information.

Comment: Use PowerShell to find if all the bindings are set up correctly. https://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/jj219450.aspx

Comment: Do you see any errors, or does the file just open in the rich client? Has someone activated the 'Open documents in client applications by default' site collection feature? Has someone changed the document library settings to 'Open in the client application' (under advanced settings for the library)?

Comment: @AndyDawson I created the new Site Collection. So all settings are default. I have already `Deactivated` the feature  'Open documents in client applications by default'. In Library Settings its selected option is 'Use the server default'

Comment: @Christoffer I have gone through that and output is pasted here... http://pastebin.com/aRkxRPew 
In most cases DefaultAction is False but I tried for PDF also. It didn't open

Comment: It should be set to true.. try this for word. Get-SPWOPIBinding -Action "view" -Application "Word"| Set-SPWOPIBinding -DefaultAction